# PHP Facebook Webdriver Click issues

Tags: php, facebook, selenium

I am very new to PHP and just got everything up and running. I am trying to self teach and I don't understand why my click function is failing. It sometimes will not process at all and other times I get the following error:   https://www.screencast.com/t/ogZPogsLXjJ

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; 
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::firefox());
$driver->get('https://github.com');
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]/a'))->click();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

```
$element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/nav/ul/li[2]/a'));
if ($element->isDisplayed()) {
    $element->click();

}
```